# Nginx: How to avoid server_name duplicate warning

Tags: https, redirection, nginx

I serve a site from nginx that is available both with internal host names as well as external ones. I want to force external access to use https, but keep http for internal access (because I can't get certificates for those internal addresses).

The following configuration does what I want:

```
#redirect port 80 http to 443 https
server{
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    #just for external access
    server_name hostname.external_domain;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# serve both http and https internally
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name hostname hostname.internal_domain hostname.external_domain;

...
```

but `nginx -t` gives me the warning

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "hostname.external_domain" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
```

because this hostname is used in both server definitions. But it needs to be there, or else I either won't catch the http access attempt or the redirected one.

I know I could add a 3rd server definition with just port 443 and without port 80 for `hostname.external_domain` and remove just this name from the 2nd server and this would probably remove the warning, but that I'd had to copy the whole content of the server block too, which I find kind of redundant.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1.

Use three `server` blocks (as mentioned in your question) but offload the duplicated content into a separate file, using an `include` directive to pull it into each of the relevant `server` blocks. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) for details.

---

Option 2.

The `default_server` does not need a `server_name` statement. However, you should swap the `default_server` to the other `server` block, so that the 1st `server` block becomes the more specific one.

For example:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name hostname.external_domain;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    ...
}
```

The second `server_block` does not need to match using a `server_name` as it will match anything that the first `server` block does not explicitly match.